# Schema per tenant in eclipselink using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

I have an application which uses EclipseLink as a JPA provider and spring boot, in that, I want to implement schema per tenant multi-tenancy. I have gone through [documentation](https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm#:%7E:text=The%20%40Multitenant%20annotation%20specifies%20that,entity%20or%20mapped%20superclass%20level.)
and used @Multitenant annotation, but I want to know how can we 1) switch between schema based on the request and 2) create a new schema with tables automatically whenever a new tenant is accessed.

Comment: I've not tried using multitenancy in spring, but it would need to have a way to access the tenant information. see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant which suggest you can let spring manage a single EMF and you just need to then pass in tenant info when obtaining an EntityManager via Spring hooks, but for schema management, I've only ever done this myself using an EMF per tenant, and never tried to use JPA's automatic schema creation as it really slows down the 'first' requests for a tenant (even if the schema exists, this is slow when the context isn't in memory)

Comment: You would be better off with your own system for schema creation that checks if the user exists (possibly in a single/central database) and if the schema was already created. If it wasn't created, then use JPA's schema management to create the schema for that tenant using javax.persistence.Persistence.generateSchema directly when required instead of risking overhead to 'first' and seemingly (to users) random requests there after depending on your server setup and restarts.